# Как закрасить только прозрачную ВНУТРЕННЮЮ часть картинки при клике

Tags: javascript, css, scss

Как закрасить только прозрачную ВНУТРЕННЮЮ часть картинки при клике применяя css стили. В одном случае представим, что картинка формата png. В другом - svg.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему бы не добавить обычный цветной бекграунд вместо закрашивания? Непрозрачные части всё равно будут закрывать его... Или это произвольная фигура, и из непрозрачного - только черная линия?

Comment: background закрасит по всей ширине и высоте размера картинки. Да, из непрозрачного только чёрная линия

Comment: если SVG то просто закрасить и всё - там не сложно

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/gOrpYOd - примерно так

Comment: спасибо, в инете подобной инфы не нашёл

Comment: Непонятно как это делается, взял другую картинку, попробовал сделать похожие действия, красит только линию (